# Marking automatically moved to folders (using rules) messages as Unread in Outlook 2010 / Gmail

Tags: email, microsoft-outlook-2010, gmail, imap

When using outlook 2010 and Gmail / IMAP using a rule to move a message to a folder also marks it as read. There is a previous question on this topic but no answers that work for me. The first answer says that should not happen (incorrect when using gmail / IMAP) and the second offers a VBA option that does not appear to do anything. I tried this code with no luck:

`Sub unread(MyItem As MailItem)
MyItem.unread = True
End Sub`

Any suggestions other than don't use outlook with gmail (which I wish was an option)? Do I need to move the message with vba also?

EDIT: No, mark as read is not checked.

Comment: This may seem like a silly question, but is the "*Mark as read*" option selected within the rule settings? Sometimes Outlook thinks you want it marked as read when it is moved.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [Items.ItemAdd](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff869609.aspx) event

[How to process incoming messages in Microsoft Outlook](http://www.outlookcode.com/article.aspx?id=62)

The code goes in the built-in ThisOutlookSession module.

**You monitor each folder separately!**

Declare an Items collection object for **each** folder WithEvents

Instantiate **each** Items collection object in the Application_Startup event handler

Add an ItemAdd event handler for **each** Items collection object

```
Option Explicit

' Sample folder directly under the inbox
Private WithEvents SubfolderAItems As Items

' Sample folder directly under SubfolderA 
Private WithEvents SubfolderBItems As Items 

Private Sub Application_Startup()

    Dim objNS As NameSpace
    Set objNS = Application.Session

    ' instantiate objects declared WithEvents
    Set SubfolderAItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("SubfolderA").Items
    Set SubfolderBItems = objNS.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox).Folders("SubfolderA").Folders("SubfolderB").Items

    Set objNS = Nothing

End Sub

' Note: Changes behaviour of dragging items into the folder as well.
Private Sub SubfolderAItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Item.unread = True
End Sub  

Private Sub SubfolderBItems_ItemAdd(ByVal Item As Object)
    Item.unread = True
End Sub
```